# Specflow.Autofac IDisposable not called at the end of the test

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autofac, specflow

I am using Specflow, Selenium and Autofac to write a simple test for https://bstackdemo.com. I am using Specflow with Selenium pattern described [here](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/ui-automation/Selenium-with-Page-Object-Pattern.html). I am trying to understand why Chrome Driver is not closed at the end of the test.

Below is the BrowserDriver and DI container setup for `Specflow.Autofac`, you can find the full solution [here](https://github.com/gkalnytskyi/BrowserStackDemoTest).

```
namespace BrowserStackDemoTest.Support
{
    public class BrowserDriver : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Lazy<IWebDriver> _currentWebDriverLazy;
        private bool _isDisposed;

        public BrowserDriver()
        {
            _currentWebDriverLazy = new Lazy<IWebDriver>(CreateWebDriver);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Selenium IWebDriver instance
        /// </summary>
        public IWebDriver Current => _currentWebDriverLazy.Value;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the Selenium web driver (opens a browser)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IWebDriver CreateWebDriver()
        {
            //We use the Chrome browser
            var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");

            var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);

            return chromeDriver;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the Selenium web driver (closing the browser) after the Scenario completed
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_isDisposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (_currentWebDriverLazy.IsValueCreated)
            {
                Current.Quit();
            }

            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}


namespace BrowserStackDemoTest.Support
{
    public static class TestDependencies
    {
        [ScenarioDependencies]
        public static ContainerBuilder CreateContainerBuilder()
        {
            // create container with the runtime dependencies
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            //builder.RegisterType<BrowserDriver>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<BrowserDriver>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterTypes(
                typeof(TestDependencies).Assembly.GetTypes().
                    Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(BindingAttribute))).ToArray()).
                InstancePerDependency();

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

If I register `BrowserDriver` as `SingleInstance()` in `CreateContainerBuilder()` and run a test from Visual Studio test explorer, then `Dispose()` method of `BrowserDriver` is not be called at the end of the test, meaning ChromeDriver process continues to run. However, if I change registration to `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`, then `Dispose()` is called and driver process is terminated.

Because Container/ContainerBuilder is recreated for each scenario and and the fact that `Autofac` [guaranties](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html?highlight=IDisposable#automatic-disposal) that IDisposable will be invoked at the end of each lifetime scope, I would expect that `SingleInstance` scope will work the same way as `InstancePerLifetime` scope, but it didn't.

Do I misunderstand how `IDisposable`, or Autofac works? Or am I missing anything in `Specflow.Autofac` configuration?

Comment: Autofac does dispose singletons when the container is disposed (we have several tests to ensure that's the case) so I'd spend time looking more into the Specflow side of things and when it disposes the container.

Comment: Thank you, @TravisIllig! I've raised an issue with Specflow project: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/2512 . It could also be Visual Studio Test Runner issue.